# How to convert java based bean configuration to xml based config

Tags: java, spring

I'm a newbie to spring and wonder how java based configs can be converted to xml based bean configs. I know that annotation based configs are more used now a days. But my requirement is to use xml based configs.
Bean configuration is added below.

```
@Bean
DataStoreWriter<String> dataStoreWriter(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration hadoopConfiguration) {
    TextFileWriter writer = new TextFileWriter(hadoopConfiguration, new Path(basePath), null);
    return writer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create bean directly in xml configuration

```
<bean id="dataStoreWriter" class="TextFileWriter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="hadoopConfigBean"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <bean class="Path">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="/tmp"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

If you need non-trivial bean configuration then you can use factory method call in xml configuration

```
<bean id="dataStoreWriter" class="DataStoreFactory" factory-method="dataStoreWriter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="hadoopConfigBean"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="/tmp"/>
</bean>
```

Factory class should look like

```
public class DataStoreFactory {

  public static DataStoreWriter<String> dataStoreWriter(Configuration hadoopConfiguration, String basePath) {
    // do something here
    TextFileWriter writer = new TextFileWriter(hadoopConfiguration, new Path(basePath), null);
    return writer;
  }
}
```

Comment: How to set null value for the constructor arg CodecInfo in this ?

Comment: null value can be passed to argument with special tag <null/>
    <constructor-arg index="1"><null/></constructor-arg>

Answer (score 1):

[From spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html)

> @Bean is a method-level annotation and a direct analog of the XML  element. The annotation supports most of the attributes offered by , such as: init-method, destroy-method, autowiring, lazy-init, dependency-check, depends-on and scope.

When you annotate method `@bean` spring container will execute that method and register the return value as a bean within a BeanFactory. By default, the bean name will be the same as the method name.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
@Bean
public TransferService transferService() {
    return new TransferServiceImpl();
}
}
```

Note :Use [@bean along with @configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-basic-concepts)